# Can't access GCP container ports externally

Tags: networking, firewall, docker, tomcat, google-compute-engine

I have set up a containerized instance on Compute Engine and spun up a docker instance of tomcat.

I have a docker-compose.yml file that maps 8080:8080 to the container for tomcat.

I am also spinning up a mongo db which is referenced in the docker-compose.yml file on the default port for it.

The OS instance shows internal and external IP addresses and I have even set up firewall rules to open up port 8080.

If i do a network test internally it reports that the packet arrives but ANY attempt to access the IP address plus port just does not work?

`wget http://myipaddress:8080/api/users`
just hangs

External port scanners also report all ports closed.

I am tearing my hair out as I have been through many pages trying to understand why...

Any help really appreciated.

Comment: Did you enable the ingress ports in the firewall?

Answer (score 1):

With John on this one, you're likely missing or have incorrectly set up your ingress rule. You'll want to use something like below, though not exact.

Direction:

- Ingress

Action:

- Allow

Targets:

- Specific target tags *input a network tag assigned to the VM*

IP Range:

- *IP range(s) you want to be able to access your app*

Protocols and Ports:

- 8080